# Overriding control+s (save functionality) in browser

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to override the browser save shortcut i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to give the functionality of save in my web App , I am using Google Chrome... I tried keydown listener to observe the keycode but when two keys i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> are pressed simultaneously, keycode of <kbd>S</kbd> is never returned in event object.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You receive two keydown events: The first is for the control key, and the second is for the letter with the modifier flag turned on. Here's how you listen for a key with a modifier pressed:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Process event...
  }
}, false);
```

`keyCode === 83` corresponds to <kbd>S</kbd> key press.

Taking a page from Google Docs, it uses Cmd-S on Mac and Ctrl-S on other platforms.

Comment: what is the 3rd arg for? false?

Comment: @user11810894 that specifies whether the event handler should be called in the capture or bubbling phase of the event - see [here](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) for more information on that. It defaults to `false` though, so it technically isn't needed here.