# Ctrl+S preventDefault in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, preventdefault

I Want to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in Chrome, and prevent the default browser behavior to save the page. How?

(Just posting the question & answer as I was after this for a pretty long time and didn't find a solution)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding control+s (save functionality) in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446987/overriding-controls-save-functionality-in-browser)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As far as I can see, the secret sauce is, that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> does NOT fire the keypress event, only the keydown event.

Using [jQuery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys):

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+s', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Ctrl+S');
    return false;
});
```

Only with jQuery:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 83)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Ctrl+S');
    return false;
  }
});
```

**Edit 2012.12.17** - jQuery.hotkeys says

> Hotkeys aren't tracked if you're inside of an input element (unless you
>   explicitly bind the hotkey directly to the input). This helps to avoid
>   conflict with normal user typing.

Comment: jQuery.hotkeys does not seem to capture the event when a textarea or input field is focused.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt very true thanks. Quoted docs as this is a documented "feature"

Comment: Tip: Do not use `keyup`, this will always trigger the save dialog first. Always go for `keydown`.

Comment: Tip: Do not use jQuery, this will only bring sadness.

Answer (score 31):

"Borrowed" from [Overriding control+s (save functionality) in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446987/overriding-controls-save-functionality-in-browser)

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key === 's' && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('captured');
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Note, in 2k21 [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated, it's [recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) to use `keyboardEvent.key === 's'` nowadays... Actually, why comment when I can edit >:D

Answer (score 6):

```js
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;//Get event
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        var c = e.which || e.keyCode;//Get key code
        switch (c) {
            case 83://Block Ctrl+S
                e.preventDefault();     
                e.stopPropagation();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

All in one solution to prevent data

```
// disable right click
$(function() {
    $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}); 

// Prevent F12      
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 123) { // Prevent F12
        return false;
    } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 73) { // Prevent Ctrl+Shift+I        
        return false;
    }
});

//stop copy of content
function killCopy(e){
    return false
}
function reEnable(){
    return true
}
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
    if (window.sidebar){
    document.onmousedown=killCopy
    document.onclick=reEnable
}

// prevent ctrl + s
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 83)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```