# javascript how to detect keyboard input

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

when focusing on a certain input,
user press kind of combination key such as "ctrl+e",
I would like to show "ctrl+e" in the input.

next time user press another combination key,
it will clean input and show the new one.

how can I make this?
I look for some javascript plugins,
but they are most for detecting certain input.

like this:
https://github.com/OscarGodson/jKey

```
$("input").jkey("i",function(){
    jkey.log("You pressed the i key inside of an input.");
});
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: you need to listen to onkeypress or onkeydown.  see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14562869/1264548)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all browsers allow the catching of cntrl keypress. This would work for the rest

```
$( document ).keypress(function(e) {
    var ch = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    if(e.ctrlKey){
      console.log('cntrl+'+ch+' was pressed');
    }else{
      console.log(ch+' was pressed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (no plugin needed) it to just use .ctrlKey property of the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) that gets passed in. It indicates if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> was pressed at the time of the event, like this:

```
$(document).keypress("c",function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey)
    alert("Ctrl+C was pressed!!");
});
```

## Update

```
$(document).on('keypress','input',function(e){
    if ( e.ctrlKey && ( String.fromCharCode(e.which) === 'c' || String.fromCharCode(e.which) === 'C' ) ) {
        console.log( "You pressed CTRL + C" );
    }
});
```

Comment: I have no idea of what user will press in the input,
if I use this way, I have to write many functions for all kind of possible inputs?