# prevent Save dialog to appear on Ctrl S

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save page changes when <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-Enter</kbd> is pressed

<kbd>Ctrl-Enter</kbd> works fine but on <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> I cannot prevent a `Save dialog` to appear.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){    
    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCOde == 83)){
        e.preventDefault();
        // save data...
    }
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable save as dialog in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710702/how-to-disable-save-as-dialog-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Typo in your code
e.keyC**O**de == 83 ===> e.keyCode == 83 [Character "O" should be small]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use :

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (!((String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase() == 's' || event.keyCode == 13) && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) return true;
    alert("Ctrl-S pressed");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Another choice is that you can use [Shortcut](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/#) library, you can enjoy more shortcut keys than just `ctrl+s`. Plus, this library has short & handy code as well :

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+S",function() {
    alert("Hi there!");
});
```