# e.preventDefault() does not prevent default functionality of CTRL + s if it opens a new tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, search, add-on, preventdefault

I'm writing this piece of code to allow me to quickly search for the highlighted text on a webpage using a firefox plugin. I have the code publicly hosted [here](https://github.com/WNM-Code/QuickSearchKeyComboExtension/tree/attempt_ctrl_s).

My function to capture the keypress `ctrl+s` and do the search is the following:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
// Help came from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14562869/6897392
 if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)){
   text = getSelectionText();
   if(text != ""){
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(text);
      openInNewTab(searches[default_search]+text);
   }
 }
}, false);
```

If I comment out the `openInNewTab(searches[default_search]+text);` line, which is the following function:

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
// Help came from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384018/6897392
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
  return false;
}
```

It will prevent the save dialogue. However, if I leave the code in, it will prevent the save dialog in the original tab, but the new tab that it opens will pop up the save dialogue.

I have had no luck figuring out how to prevent the save dialogue from appearing in the second window, and would like some help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really doing what you describe, that sounds like a bug in Firefox, but you should be able to work around it by delaying your `openInNewTab` call **very** briefly:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
// Help came from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14562869/6897392
 if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)){
   text = getSelectionText();
   if(text != ""){
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(text);
      setTimeout(() => {                                // ***
          openInNewTab(searches[default_search]+text);
      }, 50);                                           // ***
   }
 }
}, false);
```

Firefox's popup blocker should allow it, because it's scheduled within a user-initiated event.

Comment: I'll have to give it a shot! I attempted to do the set timeout before, but my syntax looked different from yours. If that does not work and it does seem to be a bug, I'll contact Mozilla about it. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I just changed it to your suggestion and it works perfectly. I'm setting your comment as the answer; thank you again!

Comment: @WilliamMcCall - No worries! :-) I would narrow it down to an MCVE and report it as a bug to Mozilla.