# Catch combination ctrl + n before internet browser using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keyboard-events

I am using AngularJS in my application and I want to use combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to go to state and view responsible for creating new objects in my application. The problem is that this combination opens a new windows in my internet browser.

The question is: is it possible to prevent this combination and use it to go to a new view in my app?

I know about `ng-keyup` directive, what's more I can catch single keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, but I would like to catch combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and go to a new view.

Right now I have following code:

**HTML**:

```
ng-keyup="keyPress($event)
```

**Angular**:

```
$scope.keyPress = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        var i = 2;
    }   
};
```

Unfortunately method `preventDefault()` doesn't work, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> still opens a new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use preventDefault() at this point.
The character n should be the keycode 78

```
 $(document).keydown(function (objEvent) {
  if (objEvent.ctrlKey && objEvent.keyCode== 78) {
   objEvent.preventDefault();

   ...
 });
```

edit

Comment: still does not work - it doesn't see property "Ctrl" as true even though keyCode is equal 17.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295508/javascript-capture-browser-shortcuts-ctrlt-n-w try your luck here :)

Comment: I've already seen it. The problem is that javascript catches ctrl or other key - only one at a time. So these conditions in if-else statement are always false and do not work for me.

Comment: OK, it works only for some combinations (for example: CTRL + '+'). Unfortunately it doesn't work for CTRL + N...

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: Did you already try to change the event from Keypress to Keydown or Keyup? There is a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000826/ctrls-preventdefault-in-chrome