# Prevent focus to URL bar with CTRL + L

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a terminal-like modal, using bootstrap's and I want to clear it when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> like it does when he writes `clear` in it.
But the problem is, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, it focuses the URL bar, and I don't have anymore focus on my page.
In this part, alert is showing, but it still focuses URL bar after :

```
if(event.key == "l" && event.ctrlKey)
    alert("clear it");
```

I have tried several things like focusing my terminal after a sec, or things like that. But nothing worked.
Have you got any ideas ? Thanks you !

Comment: try `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` from inside the if condition

Comment: Check to see if this helps at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000826/ctrls-preventdefault-in-chrome

Comment: I hate it when web applications override standard browser shortcuts like this. Flash in Chrome does it, and it's really annoying.

Comment: [Have a look at this snippet](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/disable-ctrl-n-and-other-ctrl-key-combinations-in-javascript.html)

Comment: @Barmar Well, I'm working on a terminal .. It is very boring to write `clear` to clear it. And everybody working on Unix know `Ctrl+L`, I couldn't use something else.

Comment: Good point, this may be the exceptional case where it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it wasn't hard as I thought it would be.
The only thing which worked was `e.preventDefault()`, I tried `return false` but it didn't.

```
if(event.key == "l" && event.ctrlKey)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
    // what I wanted to do
}
```

Thank you all for your quick answer and [Pawan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400876/pawan) for yours in particular.

Comment: Sidenote: Does not to work with `keyup`. Still focusing the URL bar. But yes, works with `keydown`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. But if you press <kbd>L</kbd> two times without leaving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> it will not work.

sorry but I am using *jQuery*, but I hope you got the logic.

```
var key = '';
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  key += e.keyCode;
  console.log(key);
  if (key === '9176' || key === '1776'){
    key = '';
    console.log('stopped');
    return false;
  }
});
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  key = '';
});
```

an example http://jsbin.com/xicegu/3/edit

Comment: 91 is keycode for cmd in mac. since it is a possiblity i added it :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Barmar, but here you go:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
if ((navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey) && e.keyCode === 76) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

return true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8L23u9v/