# Stop keyboard home button functionality in browser

Tags: javascript, events, keypress, keyboard-events

I want to disable home button event in browser. I am trying this code

```
var blockHome = function (e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 36) {
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
  }
};
```

it is not working.

Anybody having idea please help.

Comment: I've done something similar to prevent [`Ctrl+L`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390173/prevent-focus-to-url-bar-with-ctrl-l) and I didn't need `return false;` in the code.

Answer (score 2):

> Use `keydown` event and based on the condition, apply `e.preventDefault();`

```js
var blockHome = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 36) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
document.getElementById('blocked').addEventListener('keydown', blockHome);
```

```html
<input type="text" id='blocked'>
```

*To prevent `scroll-up` behavior of `document`, attach event on `document`*

```js
var blockHome = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 36) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', blockHome);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: in above code it is working for element I need for document